# React Native Arabic Date Picker

Tags: react-native, datepicker, calendar

[image]

How can I change the Date Picker to Arabic ?
I have used react-native-hijri-date-picker-android to get the Hijra calendar but its still in English, is there a way to display the Georgian and Hijra together in Arabic or at least one of them in Arabic ?

Comment: This library might be useful to you just check it once.[link](https://github.com/Codelabsys/react-native-hijri-date-picker-android)

Answer (score 0):

I don't read arabic myself but this be something that would work for you?

[image: Arabic react native datepicker]

You find it here:
https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker